# Powershell - If statement to validate foreach replace script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

Please note: I'm very new at powershell, but I have written several simple scripts that produce the results I require; however, this one I can't seem to puzzle (or google) out!

I'm trying to write a script that will go through the contents of an HTML file and replace a specific text string with a new text string. However, if the string that is found matches a specific string type that should not be replaced, it won't be replaced.

Let me give you the whole setup:

```
$filePath = "C:\test.htm"
$fileContents = Get-Content $filePath

#Get the variable list values
$varList = Get-Content "C:\list_of_variables_to_be_searched.txt"

#The C:\list_of_variables_to_be_searched.txt" file contains the variable name, then a
 period, then the replace value. For example, slct.<html information to replace
 where "slct" is found>.
#Assign each element split by the period into a single array
$arrayMix = @()

foreach ($var in $varList)
{
    $z = $var.split(".")
    $arrayMix += $z
}

#Split the arrayMix into two other arrays (varName and varValue)
$varName = @()
$varValue = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -le $arrayMix.Length-1; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 2 -eq 0) # Finds even numbers
    {
        $arrayMix[$i].Trim()
        $varName += $arrayMix[$i]
    }
    else
    {
        $arrayMix[$i].Trim()
        $varValue += $arrayMix[$i]
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is search through each line of the $fileContents searching for each varName in the array and replacing it with varValue.

I have this working using the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le $varName.Length-1; $i++)
{
    foreach ($line in $filePath)
    {
        (Get-Content $filePath) |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace $varName[$i],$varValue[$i]} |
        Set-Content $filePath
    }
}
```

However, there are instances where the varName may be present with an underscore character before it (e.g., _slct). Those are being replaced using the above script, and that is causing problems.

I have searched and searched for a way to use if/else in a foreach loop, but the examples have not been helpful in solving this problem.

I tried this first:

```
foreach ($line in $fileContents)
{ 
    if ($line.Contains("slct_"))
    {
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        $line = {$_ -creplace $varName[1],$varValue[1]}
    }
}
```

But, as I'm sure you who are more experienced with Powershell know, that doesn't work.

I next decided to try breaking everything into arrays and just cycling through them like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le $fileContents.Length-1; $i++)
{
    if ($fileContents[$i].Contains("_{0}" -f $varName[$i]))
    {
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        $fileContents[$i] = $fileContents[$i] -creplace $varName[$a],$varValue[$a]
    }
}
Set-Content $filePath $fileContents
```

But, again, that doesn't work either. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Is there a way to use if/else within a foreach loop? Or is there a better way of doing this that I haven't learned yet?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I have gotten this to work in testing, but I can't get this to function within a foreach loop or when the variables are actually calling specific indices of an array.

```
$string = "this is _test to see if test works"
$var1 = "test"
$var2 = "WIN"

$test = [regex]::replace($string, '(?<!_)'+$var1, $var2)
Write-Host $test
```

When trying this, per previous posts, it doesn't so anything:

```
$string = "this is _test to see if test works"
$var1 = "test"
$var2 = "WIN"

$test = $string -creplace "(?<!_)" $var1,$var2
Write-Host $text
```

Answer (score 0):

-creplace does a regular expression match, and with regexes you can say 'match this only if it isn't proceeded by something' using negative look behind. For example this regex:

```
(?<!_)Test
```

Says "match Test only if it isn't preceeded by a _". So try changing your -creplace clause to something like:

```
-creplace "(?<!_)" + $varName[$i], $varValue[$i]
```

To match on varName only when it is not preceeded by an underscore.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great site to learn more about regexes, including this negative look behind.

As for doing if/else inside a foreach you can just put an if/else statement inside the script block, e.g.

```
$input | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -eq "Test") { "X" } else { "Y" } }
```

Would output "X" if the input line was "Test", otherwise it would output "Y".

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how I can get all of the other variables ($i and $a) into the loop wihtout a for loop cycling through them. I use the $i variable from the for loop to cycle through the various $varName variables to match whether it contains the value or not. I can't simply put the for look in the else statement to cycle through the $varName and $varValue variables there because it won't be included in the IF portion. I'm also unclear on which of the two examples I have above you are basing this on.

Comment: The -creplace change I took from your code after your statement "I have this working using the following code:". Does replacing with the regex version not work?

Comment: No, it does not work. Below, the two instances of "slct" without an underscore and the instance of "btn" without an underscore should have been replaced. Nothing was replaced.

_slct_
ahdfjhafkhsdjk
_slct
fdahjkflhs
slct
fadshkjadsh
_slct
This is the test of slct to see if it works.
Will _slct_ be replaced?
btn
_btn

I changed the line to read: ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace "(?<!_)" + $varName[$i],$varValue[$i]} |

Comment: I'm guessing I've done something wrong? I did this test: `$string = "this is _test to see if test works"  $var1 = "test"  $var2 = "WIN"  $test = $string -creplace "(?>!_)" + $var1,$var2  Write-Host $test` and the result was the same as the initial string.

Comment: @EustaceMonk Check the regex! is `"(?<!_)"` and not `"(?>!_)"`.

Comment: DOH! Sorry about that. I'll test it later. Could someone explain how that works, though?

Comment: I noticed that I had the regex correct in my initial try of my working loop, and it didn't work there. I changed the angle bracket in my test (in the comment I made above), and it still does not replace. "test" remains "test" in both instances. If I remove the regex, it replaces all instances of "test", which isn't what I want it to do.